# Failing Spec when passing Variables to test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

This is my Spec file:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Programmes::ReportsController, :type => :controller do
  let!(:programme) { create(:programme) }
  context 'authenticated user' do
    describe 'GET index' do
      it 'responds with a 200 OK status code' do
        get :index, params: { id: programme.id }
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is my Factory;

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :programme do
    name { Faker::Lorem.word }
    description { Faker::Lorem.sentence(3) }
  end
end
```

This is my Controller;

```
class Programmes::ReportsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def create
  end 
end
```

I can't seem to get this spec to pass. The route works fine in the browser; eg

```
http://localhost:3000/programmes/{:id}/reports
```

The error I have is:

```
Failures:
1) Programmes::ReportsController authenticated user GET index responds with a 200 OK status code
   Failure/Error: let!(:programme) { create(:programme) }
   NoMethodError:
     undefined method `create' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ProgrammesReportsController::AuthenticatedUser::GETIndex:0x007fac78b1b440>
   # /Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/routing.rb:172:in `method_missing'
```

I am quite new to Ruby (and Rails). I don't think the Programme object is being created in FactoryGirl - but I don't really know how to find out if that's the case

Comment: Do you actually have the `factory_girl` gem installed and configured?

Comment: Don't know about configured but `factory_girl (4.7.0)` is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you `require 'factory_girl'` in spec_helper?